# UITableView Swift Combine static section with dynamics ones

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, corestore

The main idea is to have all sections in an array or you may suggest other solution to build a table. I had this code below to prepare data for a table:

```
enum ExerciseSection {
    case empty
    case exerciseGroup(group: ExerciseGroup)
}

struct ExerciseGroup {
    var muscleGroupName: String
    var exercises: [ExerciseEntity]
    var selectedExercisesIndexes: [Int]
}
```

As you see using this `ExerciseSection` enum I can simple check if the section is static empty or it should display some muscle group name. Also Group contains `exercises`. So I can simple a build needed cell.

So I prepare data for my table by creating an array of `ExerciseSection`.

In this concert example my empty cell is a cell which redirect me to the other screen.

Looks like this:

```
[empty cell for section 0, group for section 1, group for section 2... and etc]
```

Now I changed mind of preparing my own sections and instead I started using `CoreStore.monitorSectionedList`

```
typealias ListEntityType = ExerciseEntity

let monitor = CoreStore.monitorSectionedList(
    From<ListEntityType>()
    .sectionBy(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)) { (sectionName) -> String? in
        "\(String(describing: sectionName)) years old"
    }
    .orderBy(.ascending(\.name))
    )
```

So now my data is grouped automatically by relationships `muscle name`.

I can simple access instance of monitor and see how many sections it has and how many rows it has for appropriate section. Pretty awesome!

But my question now how can I combine monitor object which has all needed info about grouped objects and about groups with my static cells.

In my example above I have the firs element empty cell for section 0 but monitor already has section 0 as well.

So I need to have a hack to add `1 +` which I really don't like as this is a magical number and some day it will surprise me.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1 + (monitor.numberOfSections() ?? 0) // My static section + monitor sections
}
```

In the previous time I just had array of all my sections `[ExerciseSection]` so there is no needs to control code via `1 +`

I need to glue somehow my static section info and `monitor.sections`

You may never used `CoreStore` before, so never mind you can just think about `monitor` object as an object that has some groups to represent sections and these groups has items to represent rows. So I just need to combine it.

In my case you can simple see that the static cell is a first one item in the list but I am looking for flexible solution I even can't imagine how to show static cell at the middle of list for example.

Maybe as a solution I can loop through monitor objects and create my enum from it. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... The "easiest" way would be to have a computed property `sections` or similar.

Something along the lines of

```swift
var sections: [ExerciseSection] {
    return [.empty] + monitor.sections
}
```

But if the monitor doesn't have a direct way to get sections, then maybe the best way would be to simply have a list of "pre-sections".

```swift
let presections: [ExerciseSection] = [.empty]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return presections.count + (monitor.numberOfSections() ?? 0) // My static section + monitor sections
}
```

You could add a couple of functions to help you such as

```swift
func section(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> ExerciseSection {
    guard indexPath.section >= presections.count else {
        return presections[indexPath.section]
    }
    return monitor.section(at: indexPath.section - presections.count)
}
```

You do mention looping through the monitor objects, and this can be nice for smaller datasets. The downside is that you suddenly store data in memory. I don't know how the monitor works.

With Realm I've done this but only stored the id and maybe some simple data for each row.